# How to display absolute path with device name of currently opened file

Tags: c++, windows, filter-driver

The first two lines of this code showing file name excluding device name like **/Document/temp** but I want
to show also device name like L"\Device\Harddisk0\DR0\Document\temp. I am using this code to call ObQueryNameString routine but it is showing NULL.

Please tell me what is wrong with code. I think memory is not allocating 
properly.

```
PFILE_OBJECT pFileObject = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp)->FileObject;
if (pFileObject)
{
        DbgPrint("FileName : %wZ\n", pFileObject->FileName);
}

NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION objName = {0};
ULONG ReturnLength = 1024;  

ObQueryNameString(DeviceObject, objName, sizeof(objName), ReturnLength);

DbgPrint("FileName : %wZ\n", &objName);
```

Comment: You're querying `DeviceObject`, not `pFileObject`

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered using GetFullPathName function?
Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963%28VS.85%29.aspx for more accurate explanation what it does.

Comment: Your suggestion isn't applicable to drivers